# How to get list of related object in annotion when using Greatest function in django models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am having two models, a `User` model and a `Payment` model and there is on to many relationship between them. `User` has multiple `Payment`s. What I am trying to achieve is sorting the `User` model as per the `Payment`'s `created_at` field.

I am trying to modify the Queryset and then I'll be using the annotated field `latest_tran` for sorting.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ClubbedPaymentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(
        latest_tran=Greatest(Payment.objects.filter(user=F('id')).values_list('created_at', flat=True)))
    return qs
```

But I am having below error.

```
Greatest must take at least two expressions
```

So it seems like I am making a mistake when evaluating the list of `Payment`s. Or may be like I am taking a wrong approach.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit**

I am using the default `User` model for users which are there in `django`

My `Payment` model looks like this -

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField('Points', max_length=10)
    purchase_token = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default=None, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Transaction Date')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Updated at', auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Greatest` does not take the maximum, it takes the largest of the *different parameters*, so `Greatest('foo', 'bar')` will take the largest of the `foo` and `bar` column.

What you need is [**`Max`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#max). You can make use of the name separated by an underscore, so:

```
from django.db.models import Max

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
        latest_tran=Max('payment__created_at')
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its solves my problem. Thanks for the note as well.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, using the [**`Max(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#max) ?

```
from django.db.models import Max


def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ClubbedPaymentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(latest_tran=Max('payment__created_at'))
    return qs
```